# slugify() got an unexpected keyword argument 'allow_unicode'

Tags: python, django, django-models, slug, django-2.2

When I want to create new object from `product` I got this error:

> `slugify() got an unexpected keyword argument 'allow_unicode'`

This is my models:

```
class BaseModel(models.Model):
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True,)
    slug = models.SlugField(null=True, blank=True, unique=True, allow_unicode=True, max_length=255)
    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class Product(BaseModel):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User)
    title = models.CharField()
     # overwrite your model save method
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        title = self.title
        # allow_unicode=True for support utf-8 languages
        self.slug = slugify(title, allow_unicode=True)
        super(Product, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

I also ran the same pattern for other app(blog) ,and there I didn't run into this problem. 
***What's wrong with this app?***

Comment: You likely have overriden the `slugify` somewhere, by importing something else with the name `slugify`, or defining a function or class in that file with the name `slugify`.

Comment: Oh my God! You were right! I mistakenly imported `from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify` and then `from django.utils.text import slugify` in my `models.py` of blog app and in shop app I didn't import `from django.utils.text import slugify.` . Please write your answer to accept that.   @WillemVanOnsem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the `slugify` function is working in the other apps, it means that you use a different function that, at least in that file is referenced through the `slugify` identifier. This can have several reasons:

1. you imported the wrong `slugify` function (for example the [**`slugify`** template filter function [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#slugify);
2. you did import the correct one, but later in the file you imported another function with the name `slugify` (perhaps through an alias or through a wildcard import); or
3. you defined a class or function named `slugify` in your file (perhaps after importing `slugify`).

Regardless the reason, it is thus pointing to the "wrong" function, and therefore it can not handle the named argument `allow_unicode`.

You can resolve that by reorganizing your imports, or giving the function/class name a different name.

Comment: Perfect answer. Thanks! @willem-van-onsem

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade Django, that argument `allow_unicode` introduced in the version 1.9, or call the function without that argument.